# It does not appear MySQL80 service in my Services

Tags: mysql

I have installed MySQL 8.0.19(Workbench, Server, Connector J/NET, Documentation) but not completely. It asks me to write a root password when I don't have root account. I think I don't have the service because I've not logged into the root account. What happens is that I haven't created one before. May someone tell me some solution?

Comment: If this is part of the Install process, it is asking you to Enter (a new) password so that the `root` (superUser) account is not created without a password

Comment: If you left that BLANK in the install, then the password will be empty, and you can login using the `root` account and leave the password blank